# Modifying matrix values ± a specific index value - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to create a model whereby there is a line - represented as a 1D matrix populated with 1's - and points on the line are generated at random. Every time a point is chosen (A), it creates a 'zone of exclusion' (based on an exponential function) such that choosing another point nearby has a much lower probability of occurring.

[image]

Two main questions:

(1) What is the best way to generate an exponential such that I can multiply the numbers surrounding the chosen point to create the zone of exclusion? I know of exppdf however i'm not sure if this allows me to create an exponential which terminates at 1, as I need the zone of exclusion to end and the probability to return to 1 eventually.

(2) How can I modify matrix values plus/minus a specific index (including that index)? I got as far as:

```
x(1:100) = 1; % Creates a 1D-matrix populated with 1's
p = randi([1 100],1,1);
x(p) =
```

But am not sure how to go about using the randomly generated number to alter values in the matrix.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Anna

Comment: I think you need to add an example. I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve. Even if you can't write the code can you detail the steps you need to achieve and give the resultant matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about `exppdf`, pick the width you want (how far away from the selected point does the probability return to 1?) and define some simple function that makes a small vector with zero in the middle and 1 at the edges.  So here I'm just modifying a section of length 11 centred on `p` and doing nothing to the rest of `x`:

```
x(1:100)=1;
p = randi([1 100],1,1);
% following just scaled
somedist = (abs(-5:5).^2)/25;
% note - this will fail if p is at edges of data, but see below
x(p-5:p+5)=x(p-5:p+5).*somedist;
```

Then, instead of using `randi` to pick points you can use `datasample` which allows for giving weights.  In this case your "data" is just the numbers 1:100.  However, to make edges easier I'd suggest initialising with a "weight" vector which has zero padding - these sections of `x` will not be sampled from but stop you from having to make edge checks.

```
x = zeros([1 110]);
x(6:105)=1;
somedist = (abs(-5:5).^2)/25;
nsamples = 10;

for n = 1:nsamples
    p = datasample(1:110,1,'Weights',x);
    % if required store chosen p somewhere
    x(p-5:p+5)=x(p-5:p+5).*somedist;
end
```

For an exponential exclusion zone you could do something like:

```
somedist = exp(abs(-5:5))/exp(5)-exp(0)/exp(5);
```

It doesn't quite return to 1 but fairly close. Here's the central region of `x` (ignoring the padding) after two separate runs:
 [image: graph of two runs]

Comment: This is a really interesting approach. Thank you very much. I'm curious as to how the 'Weights' parameter is working as it's not too clear from the document - is this modifying the chances of where the second (or third...) sample can be occur?

Comment: Basically, `datasample` picks a number of samples out of a data set at random. If weights are given, then rather than all samples being equally likely, then the likelihood of a sample being picked is proportional to the weight.  So if after applying the "exclusion zone" a position has weight 0.5, it should be half as likely to get pulled out by `datasample` as one that still has weight 1. Samples marked "0" shouldn't ever be chosen.

Comment: That's really useful. Out of curiosity, can 'Weights' be applied to a specified range such as 0.0-10.0 or does it only handle 0.0-1.0 and the require you to normalise your data?

Comment: From a quick peek at the code (for many builtin functions you can see the code by simply typing `edit functionname` in the command line), it appears they normalise.  But no negative numbers, NaN's, etc.